# Stuck in Ghana with $3000

Tags: air-travel, scams, ghana

An online person claims that they can't leave Ghana unless they fly out first class. They already have $3000 and claim that isn't enough to buy a ticket and leave. Is this legit?

Comment: I've flown from Accra, Ghana to Istanbul, Turkey for less than $500US and it was coach.  You're being told a very tall tale.

Comment: We have 3000 posts on this topic and all of them say it’s fraud

Comment: I just tried to find a **first class** flight from Accra to Lagos, Abuja, Cape Town, Nairobi, Paris, London and Istanbul. I could find none, so perhaps $3000 isn't enough to charter the Lear Jet the supplicant might be accustomed to.

Comment: Classic scam. Do NOT send any money, any personal information and break contact. If it seems to be a person you know in real life, have them call you and talk with them in person, so you can ask a few questions no stranger should know the answer on.

Comment: @HankyPanky Ghana is not Nigeria.  My experience suggests anecdotally that travel-related scams like this more commonly involve Ghana than Nigeria, with Russia being another common place associated with this sort of thing.  Most of the hits for the [Money.SE] search involve advance fee fraud, sometimes known as 419 scams after the relevant section of Nigeria's criminal code.  Advance fee fraud is slightly different from travel scams like this one, although the two practices share some similarities.

Comment: Did you ask them why they must fly first class instead of economy?

Answer (score 8):

If it is an *online person,* it is almost certainly a scam.

If this *was* a real person, the best solution for them would be to contact the embassy, consulate or interests section for their country<sup>1</sup>. The embassy will help with the repatriation of their citizens, usually in the form of a loan for a ticket home. The embassy is in a position to verify identity documents.

If it is not a real person you know **in real life**, do not reply to the request, and be aware that your communications so far mark you as a gullible person. Expect more scam attempts in the future.

<sup>1</sup> There is not always an embassy, but there will be arrangements. An *interest section* is a department in a third-party country which agreed to handle diplomatic affairs.
EU citizen can go to another EU embassy. Commonwealth citizens may find help in British embassies.

Comment: "If it is a person you know in real life": since the question asks about an "online person," it seems safe to rule out that possibility.

Comment: No country would impose that you travel first class to leave. It is illegitimate in itself.